# Align object to canvas in fabricjs

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I'm trying to implement object alignment (i.e Top - Bottom - Left - Right - CenterH - CenterV) my code is working great but i don't know how to handle the alignment if the object is rotated (with the code provided part of the object disappear when the angle is different than 0, I want to know how to calculate the min left offset to be able to still see the whole rotated object). My code below.

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('a');
canvas.add(new fabric.Rect({
  left: 50,
  top: 50,
  height: 50,
  width: 50,
  fill: 'red'
}));
canvas.add(new fabric.Rect({
  angle: 76,
  left: 180,
  top: 50,
  height: 50,
  width: 50,
  fill: 'green'
}));
canvas.add(new fabric.Rect({
  left: 90,
  top: 130,
  height: 50,
  width: 50,
  fill: 'blue'
}));

canvas.renderAll();

$('.alignment').click(function() {
  var cur_value = $(this).attr('data-action');
  var activeObj = canvas.getActiveObject() || canvas.getActiveGroup();
  if (cur_value != '' && activeObj) {
    process_align(cur_value, activeObj);
    activeObj.setCoords();
    canvas.renderAll();
  } else {
    alert('Please select a item');
    return false;
  }
});

/* Align the selected object */
function process_align(val, activeObj) {
  switch (val) {

    case 'left':
      activeObj.set({
        left: 0
      });
      break;
    case 'right':
      activeObj.set({
        left: canvas.width - (activeObj.width * activeObj.scaleX)
      });
      break;
    case 'top':
      activeObj.set({
        top: 0
      });
      break;
    case 'bottom':
      activeObj.set({
        top: canvas.height - (activeObj.height * activeObj.scaleY)
      });
      break;
    case 'centerH':
      activeObj.set({
        left: (canvas.width / 2) - ((activeObj.width * activeObj.scaleX) / 2)
      });
      break;
    case 'centerV':
      activeObj.set({
        top: (canvas.height / 2) - ((activeObj.height * activeObj.scaleY) / 2)
      });
      break;
  }
}
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.19/fabric.js"></script>
<button class="alignment" data-action="left">Align Left</button>
<button class="alignment" data-action="centerH">Align CenterH</button>
<button class="alignment" data-action="centerV">Align CenterV</button>
<button class="alignment" data-action="right">Align Right</button>
<button class="alignment" data-action="top">Align Top</button>
<button class="alignment" data-action="bottom">Align Bottom</button>
<canvas id="a" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
```

How can i update the code to be able to align rotated object as well? (check the alignment on the green rect)

Comment: @HelderSepulveda sorry, i'll try to explain...if you open any graphic software when you try to align, let's say to the left of the screen, the object is still visible on the canvas. With the code provided part of the object disappear when the angle is different than 0 because, in case of left alignment, the left coordinate is set to 0. So I want to know how to calculate the min left offset to be able to still see the whole rotated object.

Comment: you should add that description to your question ... now to accomplish something like that debug your code and take a look at your activeObj.aCoords ... you need to account for all corners of your rect

Comment: the question has been updated

Comment: i'm trying on local editor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So as **@HelderSepulveda** suggested I used aCoords to dynamically calculate the coordinates, I'll paste the working code below in case anyone needs it.

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('a');
canvas.add(new fabric.Rect({
  left: 50,
  top: 50,
  height: 50,
  width: 50,
  fill: 'red'
}));
canvas.add(new fabric.Rect({
  angle: 76,
  left: 180,
  top: 50,
  height: 50,
  width: 50,
  fill: 'green'
}));
canvas.add(new fabric.Rect({
  left: 90,
  top: 130,
  height: 50,
  width: 50,
  fill: 'blue'
}));

canvas.renderAll();

$('.alignment').click(function() {
  var cur_value = $(this).attr('data-action');
  var activeObj = canvas.getActiveObject() || canvas.getActiveGroup();
  if (cur_value != '' && activeObj) {
    process_align(cur_value, activeObj);
    activeObj.setCoords();
    canvas.renderAll();
  } else {
    alert('Please select a item');
    return false;
  }
});

/* Align the selected object */
function process_align(val, activeObj) {
  switch (val) {

    case 'left':
      var left;
      if(activeObj.angle <= 90) {
        left = activeObj.aCoords.tl.x - activeObj.aCoords.bl.x;
      }
      if(activeObj.angle > 90 && activeObj.angle <= 180) {
        left = activeObj.aCoords.tl.x - activeObj.aCoords.br.x;
      }
      if(activeObj.angle > 180 && activeObj.angle <= 270) {
        left = activeObj.aCoords.tl.x - activeObj.aCoords.tr.x;
      }
      if(activeObj.angle > 270) {
        left = 0;
      }
      activeObj.set({
        left: left
      });
      break;
    case 'right':
      var left;
      if(activeObj.angle <= 90) {
        left = activeObj.aCoords.tl.x + (canvas.width - activeObj.aCoords.tr.x);
      }
      if(activeObj.angle > 90 && activeObj.angle <= 180) {
        left = canvas.width;
      }
      if(activeObj.angle > 180 && activeObj.angle <= 270) {
        left = activeObj.aCoords.tl.x + (canvas.width - activeObj.aCoords.bl.x);
      }
      if(activeObj.angle > 270) {
        left = activeObj.aCoords.tl.x + (canvas.width - activeObj.aCoords.br.x);
      }
      activeObj.set({
        left: left
      });
      break;
    case 'top':
      var top;
      if(activeObj.angle <= 90) {
        top = 0;
      }
      if(activeObj.angle > 90 && activeObj.angle <= 180) {
        top = activeObj.aCoords.tl.y - activeObj.aCoords.bl.y;
      }
      if(activeObj.angle > 180 && activeObj.angle <= 270) {
        top = activeObj.aCoords.tl.y - activeObj.aCoords.br.y;
      }
      if(activeObj.angle > 270) {
        top = activeObj.aCoords.tl.y - activeObj.aCoords.tr.y;
      }
      activeObj.set({
        top: top
      });
      break;
    case 'bottom':
      var top;
      if(activeObj.angle <= 90) {
        top = activeObj.aCoords.tl.y + (canvas.height - activeObj.aCoords.br.y);
      }
      if(activeObj.angle > 90 && activeObj.angle <= 180) {
        top = activeObj.aCoords.tl.y + (canvas.height - activeObj.aCoords.tr.y);
      }
      if(activeObj.angle > 180 && activeObj.angle <= 270) {
        top = canvas.height;
      }
      if(activeObj.angle > 270) {
        top = activeObj.aCoords.tl.y + (canvas.height - activeObj.aCoords.bl.y);
      }
      activeObj.set({
        top: top
      });
      break;
    case 'centerH':
      activeObj.viewportCenterH();
      break;
    case 'centerV':
      activeObj.viewportCenterV();
      break;
  }
}
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.19/fabric.js"></script>
<button class="alignment" data-action="left">Align Left</button>
<button class="alignment" data-action="centerH">Align CenterH</button>
<button class="alignment" data-action="centerV">Align CenterV</button>
<button class="alignment" data-action="right">Align Right</button>
<button class="alignment" data-action="top">Align Top</button>
<button class="alignment" data-action="bottom">Align Bottom</button>
<canvas id="a" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
```

Comment: Yep that does it! not the most efficient code but that will do

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this approach, the `animate` has a nice abort option that I'm using to stop if any of the corner points exceeds the boundaries of the canvas, I just tested on chrome and to simplify removed the center aligns, you can add that later if you need.

```js
function move(obj, prop, value) {
    obj.saveState();
    obj.animate(prop, value, {
        duration: 1000,
        onChange: canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas),
        onComplete: canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas),
        easing: fabric.util.ease["easeOutQuad"],
        abort: function () {
            obj.setCoords();
            for (const prop in obj.aCoords) {
                point = obj.aCoords[prop]
                if (point.x <= 0 || point.x >= canvas.width ||
                    point.y <= 0 || point.y >= canvas.height) {
                    obj.left = obj._stateProperties.left;
                    obj.top = obj._stateProperties.top;
                    return true
                }
            }
            obj.saveState();
        }
    });
}

function process_align(val, obj) {
    switch (val) {
        case 'left':
            move(obj, 'left', 1);
            break;
        case 'right':
            move(obj, 'left', canvas.width - 1);
            break;
        case 'top':
            move(obj, 'top', 1);
            break;
        case 'bottom':
            move(obj, 'top', canvas.height - 1);
            break;
    }
}

var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('a');
canvas.stateful = true;
canvas.add(new fabric.Rect({ left: 50, top: 50, height: 50, width: 50, fill: 'red' }));
canvas.add(new fabric.Rect({ angle: 76, left: 240, top: 50, height: 50, width: 50, fill: 'green' }));
canvas.add(new fabric.Rect({ left: 120, top: 100, height: 50, width: 50, fill: 'blue' }));
canvas.renderAll();

$('.alignment').click(function () {
    var cur_value = $(this).attr('data-action');
    var activeObj = canvas.getActiveObject() || canvas.getActiveGroup();
    if (cur_value != '' && activeObj) {
        process_align(cur_value, activeObj);
        activeObj.setCoords();
        canvas.renderAll();
    } else {
        alert('Please select a item');
        return false;
    }
});
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.19/fabric.js"></script>

<button class="alignment" data-action="left">Align Left</button>
<button class="alignment" data-action="right">Align Right</button>
<button class="alignment" data-action="top">Align Top</button>
<button class="alignment" data-action="bottom">Align Bottom</button>
<canvas id="a" width="400" height="160"></canvas>
```

And there are a few animation easings you can pick from:
http://fabricjs.com/animation-easing

Comment: One side effect I noticed... if the object is manually moved outside the boundaries of the canvas my abort logic triggers and the object will not move ... I guess that logic needs some polishing if the object will be manually moved

Comment: I just found a way to get things working using aCoords as you suggested, I just tested out on left alignment so I need time to replicate the logic on each case. I'll update with an answer once completed

Comment: @Mono.WTF this answer uses aCoords: `for (const prop in obj.aCoords) {`, is the animate approach not something you can do?

Comment: ..yeah i can't use animation in my project

Comment: updated with working code, thank you so much for your help!